# GPG is leaving the private keys in local, when using security key

Tags: gpg, yubikey

I have setup my Yubikey with keys (Master and Subs) and removed the Private keys from my local computer.

Everything is working as expected, but whenever I issued the command `gpg --card-status` on my Linux, `gpg` is creating all the private keys (.key) files under `.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d` directory.

The issue is, even if remove the card (Yubikey) from my computer and issue the `gpg --export-secret-key -a $KEYID`, I am able to export the private key and same for sub keys and even private key password is not prompting.

How can I eliminate the gpg not to keep any private keys on my local computer?

Comment: You said you removed the private keys from your computer, so gpg is reading the private key from the YubiKey? That should not be possible, since the YubiKey has essentially one job: to protect the private key. The YubiKey does not provide a command to retrieve the private keys from it.

Comment: Yes, I did deleted the private key using `gpg --delete-secret-keys $KEYID`

Comment: Are you sure gpg is creating the private keys on the disk, and not just listing the keys on the YubiKey. Are they really the same private keys you have created earlier? At least they don't come from the YubiKey, since it is specifically designed not to export private keys. You can even generate key pairs on the YubiKey itself, in which case only the YubiKey knows the private keys.